# Refresh data in excel after changing data in sql server in web application

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I have a web application that gets data from an sql server then exports the result to Excel.

I would like changes in the database to be reflected in the Excel file without having to re-download the file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that you can connect in this way through the web application. You can link Excel documents directly to a database though. Would that help?

For Example
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Connect-a-SQL-Server-database-to-your-workbook-22c39d8d-5b60-4d7e-9d4b-ce6680d43bad

Comment: thanks for your reply , I dont have the exact table acoording to DB taht use this way you recomand, i make a report by Stored Procedure and maybe the name of column change and make new column  in SP , then I want to Update  That excel file by changing in DB without exporting again. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can write excel document with C# code-behind with [VSTO](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/05/office-development-with-visual-studio-tutorial-series-part-4.aspx) (with Excel Document Project Template) and provide programmatic syncing DB. It is very good extensibility point - you can do almost everything: manage content, create extra menus, toolbars, ribbons etc

Alternatively you can connect Excel with DB directly and refresh data by demand.

Comment: do you have any sample project that is with excel project ? and how i can do it ? , because i export data grid to excel in visual studio and after that i dont want to export it again just by refreshing that excel ,i want data will be updated, is it any easier way to do that ?